Sending parameters via function.call()
Wondering how to make this work.
A particular IP address is associated with a particular function. (Note: In this example, I am using short people names instead of IP addresses, but the idea is the same.)
How can I pass the keyname(*) to the called function?


const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const obj = {bob:sayname, ann:sayname, ed:sayhi};

$('input').addEventListener('keyup', readme);
function readme(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
    if ( e.target.value in obj){
    console.log('got here...');
    obj[e.target.value].call(e.target.value); //<== I want to do THIS
    obj[e.target.value].call('Fred'); //<== but this doesn't work either
  }
}
function sayname(usr){
    console.log(usr);
    console.log('Name: ', usr);
}
function sayhi(usr){
    console.log(usr);
    alert('hi, ' + usr);
}
<input type="text">



(*) Which would be the IP address (being passed to the function) -- or, in this example, the human name (Bob, Ann, Ed). Basically, in the func I wish to use that IP address, so I need to pass it into the func.
UPDATE:

Here is a fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/8k0fmhdg/

The reason for using .call() is to be able to pass parameters to the function. If there is another / better way to do this, please enlighten me. I thought I'd tried every permutation/combination, but I am sure I missed one or two -- and probably the most obvious one... (That's just how I roll...)



Per mdn, the first parameter passed to call() should be the value to use as this when calling func. In this simple case, I think even passing null as the first parameter would suffice.

Why are you using call() instead of calling the function directly?

"The reason for using .call() is to be able to pass parameters to the function" yes...you can call the function: fn(arg1, arg2, otherArgs), there is no need to do fn.call(null, arg1, arg2, otherArgs)

If you just want to call the function, you don't need the call method. Just call the function.


const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const obj = {bob:sayname, ann:sayname, ed:sayhi};

$('input').addEventListener('keyup', readme);
function readme(e){
  console.log(e.target.value);
  if ( e.target.value in obj){
    console.log('got here...');
    obj[e.target.value](e.target.value);
  }
}
function sayname(usr){
  console.log(usr);
  console.log('Name: ', usr);
}
function sayhi(usr){
  console.log(usr);
  alert('hi, ' + usr);
}
<input type="text">



call is used to pass a specific object as this in the first argument, as @mykaf explains in their comment:


const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const obj = {
  bob: {name: 'Bob', func: sayname},
  anne: {name: 'Anne', func: sayname},
  ed: {name: 'Ed', func: sayhi}
};

$('input').addEventListener('keyup', readme);
function readme(e){
  const name = e.target.value;
  console.log(name);
  if (name in obj) {
    console.log('got here...');
    obj[name].func.call(obj[name], name);
  }
}
function sayname(usr){
  console.log(usr);
  console.log('Name: ', this.name);
}
function sayhi(usr){
  console.log(usr);
  alert('hi, ' + this.name);
}
<input type="text">



